# TimePicker getCurrentMinute, getCurrentHour method is deprecated in API 23

Tags: android

I'm Creating a Alarm based Application with API version 23. But TimePicker getCurrentMinute,getCurrentHour method is Deprecated. Which method will be replace of this method ?

**EDIT:**

`According to google documentation now we have to use getMinute() and getHour() method. But it's only working in api 23. what we have to do for other api?`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just check the Android official docs .. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

it tells you everything

```
public Integer getCurrentMinute ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 23.
Use getMinute()

Returns
the current minute
```

and

```
public Integer getCurrentHour ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 23.
Use getHour()

Returns
the current hour in the range (0-23)
```

Android offers runtime checks for API version.
Most of the time in such cases, you'll want to run cases like

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ) 
    myTimePickerView.getHour();
else 
    myTimePickerView.getCurrentHour();
```

@see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Comment: my minimum  api 14. it's only working in api 23. what should I do?

Comment: Android offers runtime checks for API version.
Most of the time in such cases, you'll want to run cases like 

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ) myTimePickerView.getHour();
else myTimePickerView.getCurrentHour();

@see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Comment: updated my answer with the content of the comment for better readability

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. If you write your code such as
`getCurrentHour()` (struck through), it doesn't make an issue. The code runs, gets complied, and runs saying "Complete build performed and run since...".

If you use `getHour()` or `getMinute()`, you have to put the version.SDK if-else statement (which I tried but didn't work at that time for some reason). And, nonetheless, it increases code lines and complexity.